# Accessing spesific Symfony2 Controller or Action's routes

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6

I have an annotation based Action which handles 16 routes. I need to access this action's routes. I can access through router's routeCollection but it brings all system's collections. The count is 413. Is there any elegant way to access only this routes ?

Update :
Example code which I can access the routes through route collection. I can move output to cache for further using. But I didn't like the solution.

```
protected function getRoutes()
{
    $searchRoutes = [];
    $router = $this->get('router');
    $routeCollection = $router->getRouteCollection();

    foreach ($routeCollection->all() as $name => $route) {
        $route = $route->compile();

        if(strpos($name, "newsearch_") !== false) {
            $searchRoutes[$name] = $route->getVariables();
        }
    }

    return $searchRoutes;

}
```

Comment: There probably is, add some code, and what you've tried so far..

Comment: Check this information http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#visualizing-debugging-routes

Comment: if the controller these action is in prefixes routes, `app/console router:debug | grep prefix` will narrow it down for you. But really: 16 routes to a single action? Don't you think that the problem might have something to do with re-using an action too much? SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) applies to methods as much as it does to classes: 1 block of code does 1 job, and does it well. Your action handles 16 different requests, that's just not right

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem you are correct with no doubt! but in our web site we have filtered search which handles over 30 parameters, and some queryString variable can also be a route parameter without any conflict, and some of them can be array or single. For SEO concern I have to handle those route params and queryString vars without any duplication problem.

Comment: @Naruto I added example code.